# combination related question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

suppose that  dinner cooker  has  500 mint,500 orange and  500 strawberry,and he wished to do packets  containing 10 mint,5 orange and 5 strawberry,question is  what is a maximum number of packets  he can make  by this  way?

so as i think,it is a  combination related problem,which means that  we can choose  how many   10 mint we can choose from 500 mint or

$500!/(10!*490!)+500!/(5!*495!)+500!/(5!*495!)$,but no calculator can calculate  factorial of $500$ and how can i solve it more easily?

Comment: Excuse me if I'm off track, but how are you getting that you have to find how many different combinations there are from the question, "What is the maximum number of packets he can make this way?"

Comment: does not maximum number of packets  is related to combination?

Comment: Reading it another way the solution would be simply, "$\frac{500 \text{mint}}{10 \text{mint/package}} = 50 \text{packages}$."  Can you reword your problem statement?

Comment: Think of yourself making up the packets. What are you going to run out of first?

Comment: sorry how?i did not understand   if i simply divide 500 by 10 yes,but what about other  500?

Comment: You're left with 250 of the other flavors, but since you exhausted the mint you can't make more packets.

Comment: could you explain please a little more detailed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making 50 packets, you've used up $500=50\times 10$ mint, $250=50\times 5$ orange, and $250=50\times 5$ strawberry.  There is no mint left, so you can't make any more.